# How to test custom events with Cypress and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vimeo, cypress

I need to fake the action of a user finishing a video which emits an 'ended' event. The video is a Vimeo embed wrapped in a Vue VimeoPlayer component https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-vimeo-player

When the video naturally ends, the 'ended' events gets passed to the containing component in the app. The VimeoPlayer component renders a container with id '#vimeo-player-2' which is what I've tried to trigger the 'ended' event hoping it would bubble up and be caught to register the video as watched. In my Cypress spec:

```
cy.get('#vimeo-player-2').trigger('ended');
```

in my Vue component:

```
<vimeo-player :video-id='block.content.id' @ended='updateProgress' ></vimeo-player>
```

this is what shows in test results:
[image]

Comment: Vue custom events are emitted on the Vue instance, not a DOM element. You should use vue-test-utils to test those.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out @thomas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Vue's `$emit()` rather than Cypress' `.trigger()`.

First you need a reference to the player on `window`.

I also added a data variable 'progress' to test the concept, you will have different test criteria.

**Vue component**

```html
<vimeo-player 
  :video-id='block.content.id' 
  @ended='updateProgress' 
  ref="player" />                // add a ref so we can get to the element
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    ...
    progress: 'atStart'  // just for confirming the event fired
  }
},

mounted() {
  if (window.Cypress) {   // only when testing
    window.vuePlayer = this;
  }
},

methods: {
  ...
  updateProgress () {
    this.progress = 'atEnd'
  },
}
```

**spec**

```js
cy.window().its('vuePlayer').then(myVueComponent => {

  const vueVimeoPlayerComponent = myVueComponent.$refs.player; 
  vueVimeoPlayerComponent.$emit('ended')

  // run test here, e.g
  console.log('testing', myVueComponent.progress)  // === 'atEnd'
})
```

Note, I turned `autoplay` off so that ***only*** the spec's emit triggers the event.